# How to additively merge columns in a dataframe with similar column names?

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have a large dataframe with several columns that need to be additively merged based on the first part of a string (before .S*)...

an example data frame of this can be generated with this code

```
DF1 = structure(list(taxonomy = c("cat", "dog","horse","mouse","frog", "lion"),
                 A = c(0L, 5L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L), D = c(2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L), C = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 2L)), 
            .Names = c("taxonomy", "A.S595", "B.S596", "B.S487"), 
            row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

This file looks like this:

```
  taxonomy A.S595 B.S596 B.S487
1      cat 0      2      0
2      dog 5      1      0
3    horse 3      0      0
4    mouse 0      0      4
5     frog 0      2      4
6     lion 0      0      2
```

and I would like the output to look like this

```
  taxonomy A      B 
1      cat 0      2      
2      dog 5      1      
3    horse 3      0      
4    mouse 0      4      
5     frog 0      6      
6     lion 0      2
```

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to `split` the dataset based on the names of the integer columns, loop through the `list`, get the `rowSums` and `cbind` with the first column

```
cbind(DF1[1], sapply(split.default(DF1[-1], substr(names(DF1)[-1], 1, 1)), rowSums))
#  taxonomy A B
#1      cat 0 2
#2      dog 5 1
#3    horse 3 0
#4    mouse 0 4
#5     frog 0 6
#6     lion 0 2
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
rownames_to_column(DF1) %>% 
   gather(key, val, -taxonomy, -rowname) %>%
   separate(key, into = c('key1', 'key2')) %>% 
   group_by(rowname, key1) %>% 
   summarise(val = sum(val)) %>% 
   spread(key1, val)  %>% 
   ungroup %>% 
   select(-rowname) %>% 
   bind_cols(DF1[1], .)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another version using `tidyverse`:

```
DF1 %>%
  select(matches("^B\\.S.*")) %>%
  rowSums %>%
  bind_cols(
    select(DF1, -matches("^B\\.S.*")),
    B = .
    ) %>%
  rename_at(vars(matches("\\.S[0-9]+")), funs(gsub("\\.S[0-9]+", "", .)))

  taxonomy A B
1      cat 0 2
2      dog 5 1
3    horse 3 0
4    mouse 0 4
5     frog 0 6
6     lion 0 2
```